# onmouseover div replacement script used on this site

Tags: jquery, css

I realize this is probably elementary to most here, but I'm very new to this and have not yet found my own answer.

If you mouse over the MIND, BODY or SOUL word or icon at the site linked below, new content is revealed. Can anyone point me to the technique or JS used please?

http://combadi.com

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery UI effect: http://jqueryui.com/effect/

They have many animations which can show/hide content on events such as mouseover or click.

Comment: Thanks. Any comments on how on the mouseover the text elements show in a specific order.

Comment: If you look at the documentation, you'll see that you can start an animation/effect when another has completed. Alternatively, you can also use `jquery.delay()`.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
$(".link").hover(function() {
$(".target").html("HI!");
});
```

This is a simple jQuery function. It reads like this:

If someone hovers over an element with the class link, print "HI" in the element with the class target.

http://api.jquery.com/hover/